# SVG file scaling down to 5% causes distortion

Tags: image, svg, vector, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have no idea if this can even be done; I have an SVG file in Illustrator, and it is fairly large.  I need it to be about 5% of what it is now.  I have tried holding Shift and dragging to the correct size and it's always distorted.

I have tried setting the percentages through image size, every time it is distorted. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly How complicated, the vector image is? What is the canvas size? The file size?

Check the vector point positions before and after scaling, by Alt + ctrl + Y (Pixel View) in view menu.(on/off). (*I think this will clear your problem*).

Check if your system is able to handle the amount of data that it is processing?